# Array member reference and garbage collection

Tags: c#, arrays, garbage

If a member of an array is kept being referenced, the whole array will not be garbage collected?

for example, a method:

```
    void ParseUtility(string strInput, out string header)
    {
        header = "";

        string[] parsed = strInput.Split(',');
        if ((parsed != null) && (parsed.Length > 0))
        {
            header = parsed[0];
        }
        return;
    }
```

when returning from this method, the whole string array 'parsed' will be kept as long as 'header' is being used?

Answer (score 3):

That is not the case. `string` is a class, so any `string` instance has an independent existence - each element of the array simply *refers* to a `string`, and `header = parsed[0]` retains a reference to the `string`, not to the array. Whether the array may be GC'ed depends solely on whether the array itself is reachable.

Comment: which means, .net framework always maintains objects by the smallest reference units?  - for List, HashSet etc, the framework gets its independent collections of List or HashSet's child members?

Comment: Yes; even if you have a tiny class whose only member is a single `bool`, instances of that class are individually tracked and GC'ed.

Answer (score 2):

Should not. parsed has a reference to parsed[0] not the other way around.